# Is there any SEO risk of using Javascript instead of real links?

Tags: seo

Essentially I have a client who wants to change some links from something like:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" rel="nofollow">Click me</a>
```

to something like:

```
<span style="color:blue;cursor:pointer;" id="faux-link">Click me</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#faux-link").click(function() {
        document.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    });
</script>
```

Essentially this would make the "Click me" text in the same way minus a few advanced link features (Mouse3 opens link in new tab, right clicking to see "Open in New Window" and other options, etc) also it would obvously not work for anything with Javascript disabled (or if Javascript on the page had any fatal errors)

Are there any SEO downsides to this that anyone has experienced or any kind of comments from Google or others on this type of behavior?

Comment: What you call "advanced features" are actually *vital* to the proper functioning of the Internet. What you're talking about is fundamentally breaking your website for many users who rely on the semantic meaning of `<a>` tags, and you really, **really** shouldn't do this. I mean *really* to the point where, if a client demanded this feature, I would fire that client.

Comment: Andrew: Please don't take comments personally. @meagar was  making a valid point, and he wasn't remotely 'flaming'.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example (`<a href="http://www.google.com/" rel="nofollow">Click me</a>`) you use stander `<a>` tag. But even though it uses `rel="nofollow"` attribute, some web spiders may still follow the link. A bit more on that on [Nofollow in Google, Yahoo and MSN](http://www.seo-blog.com/rel-nofollow.php) article.

In the second example you use different way of building a link (using JavaScript and different than `<a>` HTML tags like `<span>`). Googlebot can execute some JavaScript, but I do not believe it would execute large libraries like jQuery.

Please check interview with Matt Cutts for more details. Quotation from that interview:

> **Matt Cutts**: For a while, we were scanning within JavaScript, and we
>   were looking for links. Google has gotten smarter about JavaScript and
>   can execute some JavaScript. I wouldn't say that we execute all
>   JavaScript, so there are some conditions in which we don't execute
>   JavaScript. Certainly there are some common, well-known JavaScript
>   things like Google Analytics, which you wouldn't even want to execute
>   because you wouldn't want to try to generate phantom visits from
>   Googlebot into your Google Analytics.

As I understand, in both examples, it was intended to stop web spiders from crawling or indexing those links. I think (no evidence or article supporting that) that using the later approach will not affect SEO significantly.

Answer (score 0):

use normal links (if not the sites will not be indexed in google!) and use prevent default (javascript) for links that you will specify. read [preventdefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: You may have missed the nofollow on the "before" example but this is obviously the goal

Comment: ah sorry. If it's no follow and you don't want it indexed u can still use prevent default with click bind. about downsides with google: Google is just saying "good text no sponsored links and they dont care". I am sure you will not be banned for that. I have hundred of sites, planty with ajax and other stuff like that and i never had problem with google.

Answer (score -1):

The links that you want to provide in the click event are visible in the source of the page, so anybody that wants to view them can do it really easy. So, as you said, some features of legacy link will be disabled, so you can use normal links instead of jQuery.

Comment: I just used jQuery to kind of illustrate that there's some obscurity as opposed to just `onclick="document.location='http://www.google.com';"` on the span itself